# Порядок выполнения тестов в Junit не соответствует заданному через @Order

Tags: selenium, junit, allure

Переписал тесты на Junit5 (ранее было Junit4 и там порядка, если я правильно понял нет совсем).
Но всё равно Order игнорируется.
В классе теперь описание задано в таком виде:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Point;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
@TestMethodOrder(MethodOrderer.OrderAnnotation.class)
public class UserStoryTest {
    
@BeforeEach

@Test
@Order(1)

@Test
@Order(2)
...
@Test
@Order(8)

@AfterEach
```

результат выполнения в совершенно ином порядке

Comment: добавь скрипт сборки (maven, gradle  или ещё что-то)

Answer (score 1):

Если ты используешь Junit5, то используй [@TestMethodOrder](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.5.0/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/TestMethodOrder.html). Пример:

```java
import org.junit.jupiter.api.MethodOrderer;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Order;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.TestMethodOrder;

@TestMethodOrder(MethodOrderer.OrderAnnotation.class)
public class MyOrderTest {

    @Test
    @Order(1)
    public  void testA(){
        System.out.println("1. test A");
    }

    @Test
    @Order(3)
    public  void testB(){
        System.out.println("3. test B");
    }

    @Test
    @Order(2)
    public  void testC(){
        System.out.println("2. test C");
    }

}
```

Результат работы этого теста:

```
1. test A


2. test C


3. test B
```

Comment: Раньше использовал Junit4, переписал на Junit5 и добавил @TestMethodOrder(MethodOrderer.OrderAnnotation.class) но почему-то всё равно выполняется совсем в ином порядке.

Answer (score 0):

Дополнительно. Для того, чтобы заработал порядок требуется верное объявление в **pom.xml**:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Если указать зависимость на api, то она проходит проверку, но аннотации не работают.